# Play flash animation in slow motion in linux

Tags: adobe-flash, gnash

Is there any way to play a flash animation (swf-file) in slow motion (with a defined factor) in linux? I tried gnash but didn't find any options for this.

Comment: You could use `mplayer` with the `-speed` switch to slow down playback by the factor given as parameter e.g. `mplayer -speed 0.2 file.flw`. No idea if it works with all `swf` files (though it seems to be working with a couple of samples from the web).

Answer (score 1):

Open you flash animation in `mplayer` (or some of its clone as `mplayer2` or `mpv`) and play with:

- `[` and `]`: Decrease/increase current playback speed by 10%.
- `{` and `}`: Halve/double current playback speed.
- `BACKSPACE`: Reset playback speed to normal.
- `.`: Step  forward.  Pressing  once will pause movie, every consecutive press will play one frame and then go into pause mode again.
- `,`:  Step backward. Pressing once will pause movie, every consecutive  press  will play one frame in reverse and then go into pause mode again.

Comment: I think this works only if there is an embedded flv file inside of the swf file.